# Xcode configuration doesn’t change after switching schemes

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-scheme

In my Xcode project, I set up two schemes: Dev and Release; each corresponds to the configuration of the same name.

The problem is, when I activate the Release scheme, the project still uses the Dev configuration: in project details, I see product name and bundle identifier that belong to Dev.

Here’s scheme settings for Release. As you can see, the Release configuration is selected for all modes.

[image: The Release configuration is selected for all modes]

And here’s what I see in the Identity pane with the Release scheme activated:

[image: The Dev configuration is still selected]

Is it an Xcode bug or me doing something wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: M - Have you found any solution for it? I am facing problem while enabling/disabling capabilities as per different build configurations.

Answer (score 0):

If you have configured your project properly with which configuration to use for a scheme, then you can check by installing app on simulator side by side for every schemes.

Refer below post for configuration:
https://medium.com/slalom-engineering/ios-managing-multiple-environments-with-a-single-target-94cf823a6447
https://medium.freecodecamp.org/managing-different-environments-and-configurations-for-ios-projects-7970327dd9c9

Comment: Yes, I am able to install two apps side by side both in simulator and on a physical device.
However, the project area still displays Dev configuration details, and when I change project settings (enable data protection, for example), Xcode creates a new app ID on the developer portal, whose bundle identifier matches the Dev configuration, instead of adding the entitlement to the existing app ID.

Comment: Check your Product bundle identifier inside build settings is set from config file.

Comment: I checked it already: the bundle ID is different for Dev and Release, just as I intended.

Comment: I tried enabling data protection on my app and it adds to dev & prod configuration on portal together. So can you share some more details how have you configured your project.

Comment: I have two configurations in my project: Release and Dev. For Dev, I added “Dev” to product name and `.dev` to bundle identifier. I created two schemes, one for each configuration. When I have the Release scheme activated, project summary and build settings still display details for Dev (product name ending with “Dev” and bundle ID, with `.dev`). And when I try to enable data protection (the Release scheme is still active), a separate app appears on the developer portal, with its ID ending with `.dev`, and the created entitlements file has “Dev” in its name.